# Can anyone help me solve this pygame TypeError I get with my code?

Tags: python, pygame

Hello I am new to stack overflow and python and I need some help with this coding error I get. I followed Tech with Tim's tutorial on creating sprite movement and I'm coming across an error message when I move my sprite around.
Here's a link to the video I followed:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UdsNBIzsmlI

The jump movement seems to be working but I get an error message when I move my character/sprite more than 3 steps to the left/right.
Here's the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\PYGAME Folder\Game Code.py", line 90, in <module>
    redrawGameWindow()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\PYGAME Folder\Game Code.py", line 40, in redrawGameWindow
    win.blit(walkRight[walkCount//3], (x,y))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str
```

Here's the code using Tech with Tim's example:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,480))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), ('R2.png'), ('R3.png'), ('R4.png'), ('R5.png'), ('R6.png'), ('R7.png'), ('R8.png'), ('R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), ('L2.png'), ('L3.png'), ('L4.png'), ('L5.png'), ('L6.png'), ('L7.png'), ('L8.png'), ('L9.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')
char = pygame.image.load('standing.png')

x = 50
y = 400
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10

left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0

def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    
    win.blit(bg, (0,0))  
    if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
        walkCount = 0
        
    if left:  
        win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount//3], (x,y))
        walkCount += 1                          
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[walkCount//3], (x,y))
        walkCount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(char, (x, y))
        walkCount = 0
        
    pygame.display.update() 
    


run = True

while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel: 
        x -= vel
        left = True
        right = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - width - vel:  
        x += vel
        left = False
        right = True
        
    else: 
        left = False
        right = False
        walkCount = 0
        
    if not(isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
            left = False
            right = False
            walkCount = 0
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            y -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
        else: 
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False

    redrawGameWindow() 
    
    
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `walkRight`, only the first image is actually loaded. The others are just the filenames. There is the same issue with `walkLeft`.
See if this resolves the problem:

```
walkRight = [pygame.image.load(i) for i in ['R1.png', 'R2.png', 'R3.png', 'R4.png', 'R5.png', 'R6.png', 'R7.png', 'R8.png', 'R9.png']]
```

For more concise code try this:

```
walkRight = [pygame.image.load("R%d.png"%i) for i in range(1,10)]
```